# Is a closing PHP tag needed when using include or require statements?

Tags: php

Not using a closing tag in files that are included seem to work fine for me. Yet, in the [PHP.net manual for the include statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it says:

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
>   mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
>   end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be
>   executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end
>   tags.

This seems to indicate that I should be using closing tags on such files.

Yet, the following information in the [PHP.net manual for instruction separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) seems to contradict this:

> The closing tag of a PHP block at the end of a file is optional, and
>   in some cases omitting it is helpful when using include or require, so
>   unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files, and you will
>   still be able to add headers to the response later. It is also handy
>   if you use output buffering, and would not like to see added unwanted
>   whitespace at the end of the parts generated by the included files.

Is there a contradiction here or am I misunderstanding something? If I am misunderstanding something, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: http://hardcorewp.com/2013/always-omit-closing-php-tags-in-wordpress-plugins/ It's considered slightly harmful to close them when writing code for large existing CMS projects. The link is WordPress but I also recall being advised not to in the SuiteCRM style guide.

Comment: Then why in the first section of the PHP manual I linked to does it indicate that a PHP end tag should be used of included files?

Comment: If the original file is still in PHP mode why does the first paragraph I posted say that it is mandatory to use a closing tag?

Answer (score 0):

what PHP is telling you is that when you have and html archive you have to use enclosing php tags to use php, and the second paragraph, tells you that when using a php file, it is optional to close the php tags, because there may be more files running and the last of them may have the closing tag, because if you close the php tag when you are in a php file, you can break the following files because php execution may end unexpectedly